# Cannot remove iwlwifi module, even though interface is down

Tags: command-line, wifi, modprobe

When I run the following two commands, the first one returns without eror, but the second one gives me `FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.`

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

If bringing the wireless interface down still leave the kernel module in use, what does that imply?

Comment: After you run ifconfig wlan0 down, have you run ifconfig again to make sure wlan0 is actually down ?

Comment: Yes, I did run ifconfig again to verify.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See if `modprobe -rv iwlmvm` helps instead.

Use `iwldvm` for older card types.

Comment: `modprobe -rv iwlmvm` for newer card types.